# What's the answer to this shaded area question?

Tags: circles, area

[image: Q]

I've been thinking about this for quite long, but I can't find an answer. Problem is, I lost the given answer some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint for B:**

$6 \times 2=12$ equilateral triangles plus $6 \times 2=12$ circle segments.  Each segment is a sixth of a circle minus an equilateral triangle.

So the same area as A, since a circle is six equilateral triangles plus six segments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for A:**

You can move the inner segments out of the central disk and form rhombi. Then the black area is six times that of a third of a disk.

[image]